# How to not add host key to known host file when logging in using Net::SSH.start()

Tags: ruby, ssh, capistrano3, net-ssh

I have three bastion instances, and Capistrano connects using SSH to the bastions and executes code.

These are my SSH options for Capistrano:

```
set :ssh_options, forward_agent: true, auth_methods: %w(publickey), user_known_hosts_file:  %w(/dev/null), paranoid: Net::SSH::Verifiers::Null.new, proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new(ssh_command)
```

Every time it adds the host key to the known hosts file (~/.ssh/known_hosts).

When I try to redeploy it fails saying "host name mismatch".

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can tell Capistrano to ignore strict host-key verification by editing the paranoid option

`paranoid: false`

You should be able to solve the problem by removing your existing known_hosts file so that it gets re-built.

Comment: I finally got it working by making changes to ssh config rather than editing in capistrano

Comment: What did you have to edit in your SSH config to fix it? Edit your original question so that anyone else who finds this page has some clues :)